# How To Open Localhost With Selenium - C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, firefox

I'm testing a .Net exe web application on my local machine using Selenium web driver in Visual Studio. To view the web UI I need to open a firefox browser and connect to http://localhost:12345

When I run this code

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:12345");
```

a browser opens but just sits blank. Then I eventually get this error in VS:

'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Failed to start up socket within 45000 milliseconds. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055'

When I run the same test using Selenium IDE Firefox opens http://localhost:12345 correctly.

How do I get Firefox to open the localhost address I provide it in my C# code?

Comment: error says different port than what you've specified(9876)

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you working with? Can you check that once the browser has the blank page that the Selenium extension is activated?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.
I have managed to find a solution which I will post here for anyone who encounters the same problem.

In order to access localhost I used Selenium Standalone Server instead of Web Driver. These are the steps:

1- In class under [Setup] enter

`public void SetupTest()
        {
            selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://localhost:12345/");
            selenium.Start();
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }`

2- Download Selenium Standalone Server

4- Run Selenium Standalone Server using cmd `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-version-number.jar`

5- Run test in Visual Studio

And now it works.